# How to display only to items in row?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I Don't know how to display only two elements in row and keep last Column empty, spend almost 9h to find resolve
[Red zone has to be empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Plx7.jpg), here is react component of the card

```
return (

    <Row gutter={[24,24]}>
        {
            name.map((news)=>(
                <Col xs={24} sm={12} lg={8} key={news.id}>
                    {/*<div className={"card"}>*/}
                    <Card hoverable className={"news-card"} style={{height: "250px"}}>
                        <a href={news.url} target={"_blank"} rel={"noreferrer"}>
                            <div className="news-image-container">
                                <Title className={"news-title"} level={4}>{news.name}</Title>
                                <img style={{maxWidth: '200px', maxHeight: '100px'}} src={news.image} alt={"news"}/>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                {
                                    news.description.length > 100 ? `${news.description.substring(0, 100)}...`
                                        :news.description
                                }
                            </p>
                            <div className="provider-container">
                                <Text>{moment(news.datePublished).startOf('ss').fromNow()}</Text>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    {/*</div>*/}
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            ))
        }
    </Row>
);
```

Comment: I think the answer also depends on the content of the CSS used (which is not included in the question) ?

Comment: @Luuk css file is empty

Comment: Can you create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-template-f324v) ?

Comment: @Luuk don't know why but in sandbox everything is in one column https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mahavira-nesssi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Indeed, even with a picture i do not see your problem, see: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-waterfall-z0ggcv?file=/src/App.js